# Detecting ontouchend or onClick events in UIWebView

Tags: iphone

How can I detect an onclick or ontouchend event inside a UIWebView?
Or is this even possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass UIWebView and implement

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{   
    //Do your code here

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

**EDIT**

You can intercept the URL that was pressed using this UIWebViewDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *link = url.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"Link pressed: %@", link);

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: how do I know, which link a user pressed on?

Comment: @harekam_taj check my Edit in the answer for catching links that were pressed.

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
 -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

        UITouch *touch  = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:webView];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint([webView frame], currentLocation)){

//perfrom action
}
}
```